# Push Footer at Bottom of Parent Div

Tags: html, css

I have a simple layout where I have two Divs inside a parent Div. [[See this.]](http://jsfiddle.net/0er2u066/)
What I want to achieve is that, the first child div must take all the space available in the container [with or without content] forcing the footer at the bottom of the parent Div. Provided that this must work responsively. So that when the main container resizes, first child div still occupies the available space and footer must stay at the bottom of the parent Div.

What I tried so far is to make `position: absolute; bottom: 0;` to footer and yes, footer will stick to bottom but the first child div `(.content)` doesn't take the other remaining spaces.

Is it possible?. Please help. Thanks.

HTML:

```
<div class='main'>
    <div class='content'>My Canvas Container</div>
    <div class='footer'>Footer</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.main {
    height: 500px;
    background: #000;
}
.content {
    padding: 5px 10px;
    background: #fff;
    border: red solid 1px;
}
.footer {
    padding: 5px 10px;
    text-align: center;
    background: #eee;
}

.content,
.footer {
    display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not everyone's responses have considered your request that the solution be responsive (by which I assume you mean scale-able). If it's okay for the footer's height to be variable, the solution is easy:

```
.main {
   height: 500px;
   position: relative;
}
.content {
   height: 90%;
}
.footer {
   bottom: 0;
   height: 10%;
   position: absolute;
   width: 100%;
}
```

If the footer has to be a fixed height, the solution is still pretty easy but no longer has excellent browser support:

```
.main {
   height: 500px;
   position: relative;
}
.content {
   height: calc(100% - 50px);
}
.footer {
   bottom: 0;
   height: 50px;
   position: absolute;
   width: 100%;
}
```

Notes: Content-Box (the default element sizing method) ADDS things like margins to your stated sizes. If you're stating sizes in pixels, that's just a minor annoyance - you simply subtract borders/margins/etc from your stated sizes. If you're using percentages to build responsively...it's beyond a mess. You need to apply Border-Box, which SUBTRACTS things like margins from your stated sizes.

```
* {
   box-sizing: border-box;
   -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
   -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Please check this fiddle and code :http://jsfiddle.net/Luncqwn3/1/

**CSS:**

```
   .main {
    height: 500px;
    background: #000;
    position:relative;
}
.content {
    padding: 5px 10px;
    background: #fff;
    border: red solid 1px;
    min-height:92%;

}
.footer {
    padding: 5px 10px;
    text-align: center;
    background: #eee;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
}

.content,
.footer {
    display: block;
}
```

I have set `position:absolute` for the footer,`relative` to the parent container, and have set `min-height` for the `content container`.

You can refer these articles: [**Keeping footer at the bottom of the page**](http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/keeping-footers-at-the-bottom-of-the-page)

[**Footer at the bottom of the page**](http://www.cssreset.com/how-to-keep-footer-at-bottom-of-page-with-css/)

Answer (score 1):

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/0er2u066/3/)**

I am using the fake table layout technique to do this using `display: table`, `table-cell` & `table-row`

**Code:**

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.main {
    background: #000;
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.content-wrap, .footer-wrap {
    display:table-row;
}
.content, .footer {
    display: table-cell;
}
.content {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    background: #fff;
    border: red solid 1px;
    height: 100%;
}
.footer {
    padding: 5px 10px;
    text-align: center;
    background: #eee;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have updated the fiddle. check for the answer and tell me this is what i expected u right?

```
.content {
    padding: 5px 10px;
    background: #fff;
    border: red solid 1px;
    min-height:200px;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0er2u066/2/)

give min-height for your container to make it responsive. you can limit it by max-height. I have provided you the answer for what i understood from your question. If this is not what you expected please explain more clearly.

Answer (score 0):

How about adding a height to the .content and force the footer exactly where you want it to be by setting the px for the height?

Like below:

```
.content {
    height:450px;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    background: #fff;
    border: red solid 1px;
```

Answer (score 0):

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4dgaurav/0er2u066/5/)**

You need to specify the position of the parent div, just add `position: relative` to the parent div and `position: absolute;` to child footer, `bottom:0;` and to make it 100% width add `left:0;` `right: 0;`

css

```
body, html {
    height: 100%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

.main {
    height: 500px;
    background: #000;
    position: relative; /* add this */
}
.content {
    padding: 5px 10px;
    background: #fff;
    border: red solid 1px;
}
.footer {
    padding: 5px 10px;
    text-align: center;
    background: #eee;
    position: absolute; /* add this */
    bottom:0; /* add this */
    left:0; /* add this */
    right:0; /* add this */
}
/* div is by default block element so you don't need this below */
/* .content,
.footer {
    display: block;
} */
```

**[Edited Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4dgaurav/0er2u066/6/)**

css

```
body, html {
    height: 100%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

.main {
    height: 500px;
    background: #000;
    position: relative; /* add this */
}
.content {
    padding: 5px 10px;
    background: #fff;
    border: red solid 1px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom:30px; /* height of footer + padding in footer */
    top:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
}
.footer {
    padding: 5px 10px;
    text-align: center;
    background: #eee;
    position: absolute;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    bottom:0;
    height: 20px;
}
```

Comment: you just forced the footer at the bottom but the content still doesn't fill up all the spaces

Comment: what exactly you mean by fill up all the spaces?

Comment: the main div has black background color, the content div (which is white) must fill up/cover all the spaces (spaces) available forcing the footer to the bottom.